# GARCH(1,1) variance equation

Tags: econometrics, garch

I need some help understanding how to write a variance equation.
I have the general variance equation written as
$$
\sigma_{t}^2=\alpha_0+\alpha_1u_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2.
$$
I am wondering how to make this specific such as if I used returns on the S&P500 index. For example in this study I entered the following into EViews:
`SPr c SPr(-1)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have to estimate the GARCH model to obtain the relevant coefficients. Then you can enter them in place of $\alpha_0$, $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$.

Comment: Hi Richard, i have estimated the GARCH model already, done and analysed the results im just going back to methodology now however as this is my time doing GARCH and econometrics. i have currently got σ_t^2= 〖TSXr〗_0+ TSXr_1 u_(t-1)^2+ β_1 σ_(t-1)^2.  but this seems wrong, i may have just spent too much time looking at this and have missed something very obvious? (ps. sorry dont know how to copy and paste neat equation over)

Comment: @RichardHardy sorry forgot to tag

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

The conditional variance equation of a GARCH(1,1) model is
$$
\sigma_{t}^2=\omega+\alpha_1u_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2.
$$
(I use $\omega$ in place of $\alpha_1$ as I think it is more standard.) When you fit the model, you obtain

- the parameter estimates $\hat\omega$, $\hat\alpha_1$ and $\hat\beta_1$,
- residuals $\hat\varepsilon_1,\dots,\hat\varepsilon_T$,
- fitted conditional variances $\hat\sigma_1^2,\dots,\hat\sigma_T^2$.

The parameter estimates, the residuals and the fitted conditional variances are all concrete numbers that satisfy the conditional variance equation at each time point.

Comment: Not sure what your question really is, but here is something for starters.

Comment: @RichardHandy thank you